# For Looping Data Frame In R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Sample Data I Want to Obtain:

```
data = data.frame(year=c(10,11,12,13,14),
lag=c(9,10,11,12,13),
lead=c(11,12,13,14,15))
```

This is a loop

```
for (year in c(10:14)){
 year
}
```

I want to create a data frame using this style of loop that stores the values over the looping into new variables as shown in the sample data. This is my attempt below but it gives an error.

```
for (year in c(10:14)){
  year = x[i] = year ;
  lag = x[i+1] = year - 1;
  lead = x[i+2] = year + 1
}
```

Comment: If `year` is given, then `lag` would be `year - 1` and `lead = year + 1`. Is this what you want? Why the loop?

Comment: You can intitialize the vector and store `la <- numeric(nrow(data))
> le <- numeric(nrow(data))
> for(i in seq_along(data$year)) {la[i] <- data$year[i] - 1; le[i] <- data$year[i] + 1}`

Comment: My data are more complex but I work in school district so cannot share the data. So I make a simple example to illustrate that I am hoping to do these calculations and store the value in new column in a data frame. Thank you

Comment: `x` in the loop is a bit confusing. My understanding is that you have years and your want to find their lags and leads ? what is the work of `x` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to apply an unknown and undisclosable function to each year, lets say its `f(x)`, you can add new columns using `dplyr` as follows:

```
data = data%>%mutate(New_column_1= f(year),
                     New_column_2= f2(year),
                     etc ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help

```
library(dplyr)
data_df <- data.frame(year=c(10,11,12,13,14))
data_df %>% mutate(lag_val= lag(year, n=1, default = year[1]-1),
                   lead_val= lead(year, n=1, default = year[nrow(data_df)]+1))
```